# IDWriteFactory::CreateTextFormat() failing

Tags: c++, direct2d, directwrite

I'm facing a problem which I'm killing myself over. I have the following code:

```
ComPtr<IDWriteFactory> factory;
DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED, __uuidof(IDWriteFactory), factory.GetAddressOf();
ComPtr<IDWriteTextFormat> textFormat;
factory->CreateTextFormat(L"Arial", nullptr, DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL,
    DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL, DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL, 20.0f, nullptr,
    textFormat.GetAddressOf());
```

After the last line textFormat points to null. CreateTextFormat() returns the value E_INVALIDARG. I definitely have Arial installed, the two nullptr parameters are allowed according to MSDN, so I don't see what can be invalid. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Your supplying `nullptr` for local name is questionable, did you try "en-us" instead?

Comment: textFormat appears to be something other than null now, so it's probably fixed. It just seems odd how an MSDN example uses null for the locale name...

Comment: Does it work with an empty string `L""` and not `nullptr`? A comment on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368203.aspx) claims so.

Answer (score 2):

Like CodeAngry said, the language tag and familyName cannot be null (In_z rather than In_opt_z). Either may be empty though "", in which case no particular language is used and default fallback fonts are chosen.